# Minimal pairs with /ʌ/ and /ɑ/

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels

Would an American native speaker be able to hear a difference between **/ʌ/** and **/ɑ/** in pronunciation of "done" and "don" and recognize which one was said without a context? For me as a non-native speaker, they sound quite similar.

Comment: A native of where, Andrej? To a speaker of RP English the use of ɑ in either word ("darn") would sound like a dialectal variation. It would be understood though. If you said someone was a dʌn, it might not be.

Comment: A don is a university teacher, especially a senior one at Cambridge or Oxford, and a dun is a debt-collector.

Comment: "Bun" and "barn" are similar, but "I live in a barn" and "I live in a bun" do sound different from each other.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: These are very old debts if the guy collecting them's a dun!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, and when you're done with the debt collector, you were dunned.

Comment: In which accent? I have no trouble distinguishing don and done, at least in GAA. I’m not sure about RP; their vowels *all* sound funny to me, so I might need context.

Comment: In RP, don and done sound totally different, in the same way that hot and hut do, or cot and cut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what variety of English you're talking about. In General American English, they use /ɑ/ in words like *bot, don, hot, cot* and /ʌ/ in *strut, cut, done*. So **/dʌn/** will be understood by natives of both the UK and the US as *done*.

However, /dɑ(ː)n/ will be understood by most Americans as *don*, but by British as *darn* because British English uses /ɒ/ (a rounded version of /ɑ/) in most words where GenAmE uses /ɑ(ː)/.

Comment: So the answer is yes, they would hear a difference and recognize which vowel was said, right?

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko: Yes. Also, s I said, it depends on the accent.